# How to install firmware-mod-kit on Debian

Tags: debian, software-installation, firmware

how to install firmware-mod-kit on Debian 8 jessie? The package doesn't contain any INSTALL or MAKE file. Or FMK source just need to be extracted in some folder,

```
# tar -xzvf fmk_099.tar.gz
# cd fmk
```

and shell scripts are used to extract firmware?

Edit: Firmware Mod Kit [v0.99](https://code.google.com/archive/p/firmware-mod-kit/downloads)

[Git](https://github.com/openwrt-stuff/firmware-mod-kit.git)

Comment: Is [this the firmware-mod-kit](https://github.com/dnpinpon/firmware-mod-kit/wiki)? Please add some additional context as to what the firmware-mod-kit is?

Comment: Yes. But didn't find the official Git repository for this pack.

Comment: So did where you get it from have any instructions? Its not clear to me but according to the link this is a set of utilities and scripts. There should be no need to compile anything unless it is part of a firmware build script. Please edit your post to include these details, thank you.

Comment: Edit: added details.

Comment: It does not look like there is anything to install. Are you having any issues using firmware mod kit?

Comment: I haven't used it yet. Just to clarify: the binary should be dropped into the firmware-mod-kit folder, since shell scripts are not in $PATH?

Comment: You should not have to do that. You should be able to just use the path like so: `/path/to/shell/script.sh /path/to/firmware/binary.bin`. But I mean you could add the tools to your path or into your bashrc or however you want to do it. If you want an answer for that you will need to ask a different question.